# Direct line errored out when sending a message to bot after renewed app secret

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I recently renewed the expired client secret for my virtual assistant. Once I updated my appsetting.json and republished it to Azure. The bot received an authentication 401 error and the direct line channel errored out.
However, I can chat with my virtual assistant through my local bot emulator with the updated client secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the secret/password is setup in your web application/app service configuration, you will need to correct it there.